# Database design issue - trying to avoid circular reference

Tags: mysql, database-design, circular-reference

I have been at this for a day and a bit now, trying to figure out how to best model the database (MySQL) for an app I'm developing for a friend who owns a bakery. The assumptions are as follows:

- many (external) `Bakers` produce many `Products`
- `BakersProducts` is updated fortnightly by certain staff who either call bakers for their product prices, or the bakers fax through their pricelist themselves, which the staff then update via a front-end UI.
- the manager should be able to generate an order based on the products that she ***anticipates*** having.

So the front-end UI must be able to allow the manager to purely choose the products she would like in the order, and then present her with a list of Bakers to choose from for each product in the order.

In other words, `Orders_has_Products` should also include a reference to `BakersProducts.bpID`. I'm sure though that if I do this, then I would create a circular reference (of sort) to `Products`.

[image]

Im sure I've gone about this the wrong way, and would really appreciate anyone's advice as to how I can restructure my design to acccommodate the chosen Product Price - ie. to include `BakersProducts.bpID`.

Thank you!

Comment: I don't quite see the circular reference here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the mix-up is from a business process standpoint: you're getting **requisitions** mixed up with **orders**.

A requisition has a list of products needed without necessarily specifying the supplier of each, whereas an order is directed at a specific supplier, for specific price look-up codes (what `bpID` seems to represent).  One requisition may spawn multiple orders if it is split across multiple suppliers, and even a single product may have its order split across multiple suppliers, perhaps due to vendor volume limits or locality of delivery.

You may want to provide a *view* of a requisition that shows the order line item(s) generated from each requisition line item, but that is a user interface concern.

Comment: thanx Jeffrey, You are spot-on! I've erroneously tried to merge a *requisition* with an *order*. So ideally, I should have a intermediary `Requisition` table to show "desired" products, and then (based on that), have my `Orders` table reference `BakersProducts.bpID`?

Comment: @magz: Now that I think about it, `BakersProducts` rows are actually more like an item **price quotation** than a PLU or SKU, and certainly more than a mere cross-table between Bakers and Products.  Its true primary key should be `(bakerId, productId, bpDate)` while `bpID` is a surrogate key.  Referencing `bpID` from an order **line item** (not the order itself) would be a good way to indicate which price quotation the line item is based on.  Alternatively, eliminate `bpID` and use the entire 3-field composite key when referencing from your order, for quick linking to Baker and Product too.

Comment: @Jeffrey: thanx! Yeah, `bpID` is a surrogate as I can't reference a composite key (`bakerID`,`productID`,`bpDate`) in another table. Would you mind if I just knock this up quickly in DBDesigner to see how this would work out for me? I might have an additional question based on that if you don't mind?

Comment: @Jeffrey: You are correct with your assumption of what `BakersProducts` is envisaged to be.

Comment: @Jeffrey: have a look at this amendment [http://i.imgur.com/jeCHu.png]. I decided to include a `Requisitions` table, as it gives a great platform to generate a Comparison View (on the UI side) to allow the manager to generate an order based on the best "deal". Do you foresee any issues with this design?

Comment: @mags: I think `quantity` is missing from both `Requisitions_has_Products` and `Orders_has_BakersProducts`; additionally there may be minimum and maximum quantity limits associated with a quotation in `BakersProducts`.  Combining items from multiple Requisitions into one Order could get messy as well, but other than that, looks good.

Comment: @Jeffrey: oops, forgot the level-indicators! Thanx for all of your help!

Comment: @Jeffrey: Just one more thought on this new model...Firstly, I understand your last concern, although *this* model provides a great way for the manager to develop a "requisition charter" of sorts, that is made up of a defined set of products (example: types of muffins) which can based on a seasonal occurrence of sales. So the manager needs only to create a new `Order` based on that Requisition List (example: every 3 months if thats what the buying trend dictates), and the system will generate new OrderLineItems reflecting updated bakers prices (catering for price changes since the last Order).

Answer (score 3):

This is not a circular reference, since

- Order_has_products references Products
- Order_has_products references BakersProducts
- BakersProducts references Products

a circular reference would be if, for example,

- Order_has_products references Products
- Products references BakersProducts
- BakersProducts references Order_has_products

Aside from that, circular references are relatively normal in a database (i.e. Employees table with a manager field, where the manager is herself an employee is a one table circular reference)

What your design has is a simple redundancy, because one product is referenced twice in the Order_has_products table - once directly from the Products table, and once via the related BakersProducts record. There is posibility for getting out of sync, but, since you stated that the business rule is that the product is chosen before the baker, it's quite all right.

I would include the productID even if it was the other way around, because a little denormalization can go a long way when speeding up queries, because otherwise you would have to scan the BakersProducts table, even for simle questions, like, 'Did we have any bagels on wednesday?'

Comment: okay, thanx for clarifying the 'circular reference' issue. I just imagined this scenario to be a circular reference since a Product would take more than one route to Orders. I think though that Jeffrey's answer above helps in trying to separate an Order-Request from an actual Order.

Answer (score 1):

one way of solving this is simply to eliminate the Products table, and move productName into the BakersProducts table.

This would essentially only work if you do not expect the bakers to carry the same product, if the products are unique to the bakers.

If you do expect the bakers to carry the same product, then you may want to leave the separate Products table, but instead of having Order_has_Products.Products_productID, I would change it to Order_has_Products.bpID.  If/when you need to access the productName (or other product related metadata that may go in that table) you could just do a join between BakersProducts and Products.